# RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(vendor/magmodules/packages): Failed to open directory

Tags: error, magento2.4.5

I am trying to run project, so I run composer update.

I got error like this.

[image]

what is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of running the command `grep -rn "magmodules" app composer.json composer.lock`?

Comment: composer.json:79:        "magmodulesartifacts": {
composer.json:81:            "url": "vendor/magmodules/packages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your project no longer requires the use of `magmodules/packages`. You can try removing the repository configuration for `magmodules/packages` in `composer.json`, the configuration is similar to the following:

```
"magmodulesartifacts": {
    "type": "artifact",
    "url": "vendor/magmodules/packages"
}
```

Then run your composer command again.